# What does a dialogue consist of?  I mean, what are these constituents called?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

> **Tina**: I had a strange dream last night.
>   **Jack**: Well, dreams are always strange. I've never had an absolutely "normal" dream. So what did you dream about?
>   **Tina**: I dreamed about a skyscraper devouring a small "Starbucks"

What do you call a single part of a dialogue that is spoken by one person? (There are three such parts written here: The first and the last one are spoken by Tina, and the middle one is by Jack.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In acting, these are called *lines*

> **lines** the words of an actor's part in a play or film. [NOAD]

Normally these are used in plural, but can be used to refer to a single line of dialogue.

Comment: Hmm... what if Jack proceeded to perform a monologue? Would it still be called a line if it went over to the next page of the script? (I have no idea myself.)

Comment: It would still be his lines, but would be specifically referred to as a soliloquy in that case.

Comment: OK noted. I couldn't think of anything else either.

Answer (score 1):

You can say ***lines***, in the sense of *“the words of an actor's part in a play or film”*. Example of use:

> the problem with Jack is that, in the love scene with Rob, he couldn't say *(or deliver)* his lines with enough passion